# How to pass whole Model to partial view using tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application uses Razor view.

I'm trying to pass while model to partial view using partial tag helper.

```
@using Store.Models
@model StoreBrowseViewModel

<partial name="PildidNimekiri" for="Model" />
```

The error in Razor designer

> cs1061: 'storeBrowseViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no accessible extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'storeBrowsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How to pass whole Model to partial view using tag helper ?

PartialAsync allows this:

```
@Html.PartialAsync("PildidNimekiri", Model);
```

Comment: you can use `model` property instead, e.g: `model="Model"`, the `for` is for properties rooted from the `Model`, to use `for` you need an explicit expression by prefixing the model with `@`, e.g: `for="@Model"`

Comment: Sergey's answer which recommends to use whithout properties at all looks great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your case you can  use this way, since you use the same model for partial and for main view:

```
<partial name="PildidNimekiri" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Great. I thought that in this case object is passed for model.